# Having problems using a Switch statement in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm making a Character Creator for fun and I seem have run into yet another java problem! I tried googling around for a bit but I didn't seem to find a working solution... I'm trying to use a switch statement for the compiler to output certain information depending on what class (Knight, Archer, Mage) the user chose, but when inputting my code I get error messages

My code so far (cleaned up a bit) is :

```
    String name;
    String className;
    int attPoints;

    System.out.println("Welcome to 'GameName's' Character Creator 2.0!\n");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.print("First off, what do you want your characters name to be? \n\nName : ");
    name = Scan.nextLine();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.print("\nYou are now to be known as "+ name + "!");

    System.out.print("\n\n" + name + ", what class do you want to be? ");
    System.out.print("\n\nClasses available :\nKnight");
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    System.out.print("\nMage");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\nDruid");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\nNinja");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\nArcher");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\nAdventurer");
    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.print("\nBerserker");
    Thread.sleep(300);

    System.out.print("\n\nClass : ");
    className = Scan.next();

    Class userClass = Class.valueOf(className);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.println("\nCongratulations! Your class is now : "+ className + "!");
    Thread.sleep(500);


      // This is where I get an error.
      // - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName    
      // - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
  // - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected

    public void setClass()
        switch (Class) {

        case Knight:
            System.out.println(" Various lore about knights ");

            break;

    }
}
```

I THINK I may be trying to create a class inside another class - but when I tried putting it outside it got another error...
Also, I have an int called attPoints, and after I choose a class I want to add 10 to it, but unsure how.

Comment: First, never use names in `java.lang` for your own types; use `CharacterClass` or something similar instead. Presumably you're using an `enum Class`, and it looks like the problems are there. (1) Post the code for the enum. (2) Compiler errors specify *where* the errors are occurring. Post that information.

Comment: switch (userClass), not switch (Class)

Comment: By the way: In Java, enum types are full classes. Instead of using `switch`, you generally should define methods on the enum and provide the implementations for each value.

Comment: Okay, so my enum is : public enum Class {Knight, Mage, Druid, Ninja, Archer, Adventurer, Berserker}
And the errors I posted in the first code box all appear where I said "// This is where I get an error."

Comment: And it may be a good practice to use proper meaningful name when naming Classes or Enums - in this case GameCharacter may be a good name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're switching on `Class` which is a Java type. Take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

You probably want to do something like:

```
switch (userClass) {
    case Class.KNIGHT:
        System.out.println(" Various lore about knights ");
        break;
}
```

Comment: `Class` isn't reserved, `class` is.

Comment: Also in order to avoid writing EnumName.x for each case, the OP can use import static to get all values of the enum so that switch(x) can be used.